# MS Access find longest record from multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am looking for a way to find the longest record from more than a single field.

Specifically, I have a database of names and addresses. At times, a name field will be longer than an address. Othertimes, it could be a secondary address or the combination of City, State & ZIP Code.

Using Excel I can use the MAX function as such and sort my list in descending order:

```
=max(LEN(Full Name), LEN(Address1), etc.)
```

However, the Max function in Access only accommodates a single field.

I can certainly nest multiple IF statements to compare fields, but I would think there is an easier method.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

You could just concatenate all the fields together and look for the max length of that.

Rough example (using MS access methods):

```
SELECT max(len(Person.[first_name] & Person.[last_name] & Person.[address])) AS Expr1
FROM Person;
```

**Examples:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @maythesource.com for the suggestion, but combining multiple fields wouldn't necessarily provide the longest available. A long address line with no secondary address and a short city may be overlooked when compared to other records with multiple fields with a moderate length.

Comment: Yeh, I think you need to use an if statement then.

Answer (score 2):

I may have taken the long way around, but it will be easier to expand with field additions.

I made a query for each field I needed to compare (6 total). The queries had a new field "Length", and were limited to the highest value available.

I then made a union of all my longest fields and returned the top 1 of the resulting table.

It gets the job done, but if anyone has a more effective or simpler method, please let me know.